# MySql Too Slow on Update Query (Localhost)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, query-optimization

i have a table on Mac with localhost server. 
The table has about 2500 rows. The problem is that, SELECT query are fast enough, but UPDATE/INSERT query takes about 40 seconds!!

For example, simple query:

```
UPDATE clienti SET email = 'my_noemail1427@noemail.it1' 
                 , telefono = '348/51560931' 
                 , ragsoc = 'Tomaselli   Grandi Impianti 1S.r.l.' 
WHERE codice = 'C00518'
```

It takes 44 seconds!

The structure is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `clienti` (
  `codice` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `cap` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ragsoc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `indirizzo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localita` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prov` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partitaiva` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codfiscale` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `targa` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modello` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Contiene la password:LASCIARE VUOTA, la inserisco io ',
  `inserito_in_AC` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'no' COMMENT 'si, no. Se l''ho già importato',
  `datains` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'la data di inserimento del cliente nel DB',
  `space` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any suggest?
Thank you

Comment: Either set `codice` to and index or a primary key.

Comment: There must be more wrong than just a missing index, 40 seconds is an eternity. However, from the question I cannot guess what it might be.

Comment: it occurred to me before. try check your firewall?

Comment: @jeff Codice is primary key already... I don't suppose it would be a firewall problem, because I hosted the same DB online with the same problem... what can I do?

Comment: i tried to duplicate table, witouth data inside, and it seems work fine. So i think the problem is in the data inside. I  don't know.

Comment: @Ento - not according to the create statement that you posted. There are a couple of things that you can look at. 1) repair & optimise the table as it could be corrupted (but on different machines this is unlikely) 2) check if there are any trigger events set on the table.

Comment: I agree with KIKO Software that 44 seconds is way too long to update 2500 rows, even given the fact that `codice` column has no index, so it has to do a table-scan.

Comment: I just tested the same update against the same table, I filled it with 4096 rows of data, with all strings at their maximum length. The update takes 0.03 seconds in my test. Are you sure you don't have a long-running SELECT query locking the table, preventing your UPDATE from executing? Because your table is MyISAM, a long-running SELECT can block a concurrent UPDATE.

Comment: Suggest you provide more information: `SET PROFILING=1; UPDATE clienti ... ; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;` Run your update where I have written "...". After you run this, edit your question to provide the resulting profile data.

Comment: That's the solution!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@ento To ANSWER you question, please post a current
SHOW INDEX FROM clienti;
in your original question.

I see no evidence at this time of a Primary Key or appropriate index on column codice on this table.  Any WHERE should have a leading index of some form.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the solution guessed at in the comments above is that a long-running SELECT query was blocking updates to the table.

This is why you should not use MyISAM. Readers block writers when you use MyISAM.